# Variation of EM action with respect to boundary metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, variational-principle, action, boundary-terms

Say you have a charged black hole solution in General Relativity. I am wondering if the variation of the electromagnetic action with respect to the induced boundary metric is $0$?

I am asking because if this is the case then the electromagnetic action does not contribute to the Brown-York quasi-local stress tensor.

Could somebody please let me know if the aforementioned variation does yield $0$?

Comment: What is stopping you from computing it?

Comment: Good question. So the action is $-\int \sqrt{-g} \frac{1}{2} * F \wedge F$. I do not know if $g_{ab}$ or in fact if $\sqrt{-g}$ vary with the boundary metric??

Comment: When you say boundary metric, do you mean the second fundamental form $h_{ab} = g_{ab} \pm n_a n_b$ or the induced metric $\gamma_{AB}$ (where $A,B$ are indices on the boundary instead)?

Comment: @JamalS I mean the second fundamental form.